# Redirect page in jsp to open a new page

Tags: jsp, redirect, new-operator

Using below code I failed to redirect the page in jsp to open a new page?

```
<div class="col-md-12">

            <fieldset>
            <legend>ADD NEW FIRM</legend>
            <!-- <div class="col-md-12"> -->

   <form> Do You Want To Register a New Firm<font color="red">*</font>: 
   <div><a href="Online_Application" ><button class="btn btn-info btn-md col-md-sm-2">YES  </button> </a></div>
    </form> 


            <!-- </div> -->

            </fieldset>
            </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean in new tab? Where is your page's link in jsp code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the a tag with a button:

```
<a href="Online_Application" ><button class="btn btn-info btn-md col-md-sm-2">YES  </button> </a>
```

With submit button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md col-md-sm-2">YES  </button>
```

And set the action and target in form tag:

```
<form target="_blank" action="Online_Application">
```